# Http Post Request

Tags: http, google-api

I am trying to authenticate against google, and this is their example request:

```
POST /accounts/o8/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=21302922996.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=XTHhXh1SlUNgvyWGwDk1EjXB&
code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp6&
redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Should all the lines after content type be headers, or the body of the request? If they are headers, does a blank body suffice?

The address they say to post to is: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
This differs from the first line of the request. Which is correct?

Thanks for any help,
Venatu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was with the mime type of the message, the default type was causing the request to be ignored. The default request above worked perfectly once the mime type was changed, with the above as the body of the message, using the second address given.